# Javascript Vs Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am new to HTML5. I want to know about the performance between Javascript Variable/Object and HTML5 Local storage.

Which one is the best in performance and memory wise. Could any one differentiate these two.

P.S. As for as i know, manually we need to clear the local storage where as javascript object automatically will be cleared when the page get refreshed.

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to compare a hammer and a screwdriver.

Comment: bazmegakapa - can i know why you saying like this?

Comment: Because they are used for two different things. They cannot be reasonably compared, that is why I downvoted your question. Could you compare the hammer and the screwdriver without knowing what the task is?

Comment: bazmegakapa - they are not totally different things. Take an example, you can save the 200 - 300 mails of content in javascript JSON object which can be achieved by local storage. I am asking the performance/ memory comparison for both these type of scenarios.

Comment: In your question, you don't even mention JSON. In your question, you don't mention this 200-300 email thing. You see my problem? Btw, what do you mean by javascript JSON object? Do you send it to the server? It is impossible to give a good answer without knowing exactly what you want to do. Do you want to save these "emails" somewhere or just store them until the page is refreshed?

Comment: @kapa It is as simple as stating that they are used for separate concerns, local storage is used primarily as a persistence layer, where as one of the many uses for an Object is to store data in an Object Store that will not persist across a page refresh. So comparing the the two performance wise really depends on the application. See that wasn't so hard, I don't know why there are so many people on here waiting to trash each other. The first line of his question states 'I am new to HTML5', What did you expect?

Comment: @charlie Not knowing html5 does not mean you can ask bad questions.

Comment: @kapa I understand, just keep in mind that we are all trying to help each other where we can. And when you are not familiar with something, it is hard to pose a great question. Your profile suggests that you can offer a lot to the learning community, please try to remember what it is like being a new comer, You can help people, be that guy.

Comment: @Charlie I understand what you are saying. I remember being a beginner. I felt respect towards those having the knowledge, and did everything I could not to bother them with useless questions robbing their valuable time. I looked at lots of questions and tried to learn how to ask before asking. I do not say that this is what I expect from others, expectations don't help. But I am ready to offer criticism, which is sometimes more valuable than an answer. When you criticise, there is always a chance of understanding, realising.

Comment: @kapa I agree with what you are saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That are 2 different things.
HTML 5 Local Storage is used to save bigger data to the client. Sometimes used for making certain parts of websites to work offline.

- http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Javascript variables and Objects are programming code. I think that working with HTML Local Storage to save variables that are only used in JS Code locally is a waste of time and is much to slow for programming purpose.

Comment: Thanks EvilP. I'm not going to use all javascript variables as local storage. I want to use Local Storage instead of JSON Object say for an example saving gmail mail content for 100 mails etc.

Comment: I would always go with JSON. Using a JSON is faster than saving 100 mails to the local storage in any format which you have invented. Using JSON is a good practice and a good standard !

Comment: Any way thanks for your reply. I need this difference for large amount  of data saving in client side

Comment: Ya. Thanks. but if refresh the page without logout, local storage of 100 mails could be useful only na?

Answer (score 1):

local storage is used for persisting data,
for example, saving user preference data by using local storage.

so i think there is no comparison between local storage and JS Object